# Child div ignore parent aspect-ratio 16/9 and content inside parent and push content down

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

[image]I have parent div with `aspect-ratio: 16/9;` and inside that div I have another div with same ratio, but I also have some content with that child inside, when I set child aspect-ratio it's move content down and change height of the parent and parent lose the ratio? Is there a way for preventing this? [codepen](https://codepen.io/jezda1337/pen/LYaPXmW?editors=1100)

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-2"></div>
    <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quibusdam quisquam, tempore harum commodi beatae earum aperiam! Beatae et nulla alias.
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    aspect-ratio: 16/9;
    background: #ccc;

    
    .content {
        font-size: 2rem;
        padding: 1rem;
    }
    .container-2 {
        aspect-ratio: 16/9;
        max-height: 100%;
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Paulie_D I added ss to the question, pls check, that's what I'm trying to achieve here, first child should not push the content and should not change parent height, it should adapt like in the ss without explicit width

Comment: @Paulie_D By that I'm losing aspect on the parent, I hope there is a better solution for this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS grid

```css
.container {
    aspect-ratio: 16/9;
    background: #ccc;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr auto; /* the first row will take the available space */
    
    .content {
        font-size: 2rem;
        padding: 1rem;
    }
    .container-2 {
        aspect-ratio: 16/9;
        min-height: 100%; /* 100% height of the available space */
        margin: auto; /* center */
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-2"></div>
    <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quibusdam quisquam, tempore harum commodi beatae earum aperiam! Beatae et nulla alias.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first child is 100vw wide so it's not going conform the way you want unless, at minimum, you limit the height of the container.

Limit the height of the container to a maximum of `100vh` and then, using a flexbox column, make the first child as large as possible with `flex:1`.

```css
.container {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  
  .content {
    padding: 1rem;
    background: lightgreen;
    margin: 0 1em;
  }
  .container-2 {
    flex: 1;
    aspect-ratio: 16/9;
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="container-2"></div>

  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quibusdam quisquam, tempore harum commodi beatae earum aperiam! Beatae et nulla alias.
  </div>
</div>
```